# Automatically update firefox without asking (and without password prompt)

Tags: 18.04, updates

I'm preparing an ubuntu (18.04) machine for my elderly relatives (the computer is old, can't run win8 and win7 ends soon). I need the machine to be completely self-sufficient, as they live hundreds of kilometers away and I won't have easy access. I don't want them having sudo privileges, it would only confuse them. I know I can set security updates to be installed automatically, I would however like this for the browser too. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can try this,  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1682224

Comment: Maybe take a look at [unattended-upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html.en).